# Can't find the source of redirect

Tags: php, redirect, joomla

I have a redirection after ~10 seconds to some "dodonet.biz" wired domain
I can't find the source of the redirection.
 - Searched in all the JS files.
 - Disables the JS.
 - Searched for  tag that make the refresh.

But found nothing.

Please take a look and tell me if you have any idea what to check next

the website is: www.tmaster.co.il

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see or experience any such redirect.

Comment: It does not redirect for me. Try another browser, you may have some malware.

Comment: No redirection for me either

Comment: I am not seeing the redirect in Firefox. Can you be more explicit about your testing environment?

Comment: I'd look at browser add-ons.  Sounds like malware.

Comment: no redirect for me either

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect is in a file called decode.php in your root directory.

```
<?php

$str = "aGVhZGVyKCJSZWZyZXNoOiAyNTsgdXJsPVwiaHR0cDovL3d3dy5kb2RvbmV0LmJpei8xL1wiIik7";

echo base64_decode($str);
?>
```

Decoded it says

```
header("Refresh: 25; url=\"http://www.dodonet.biz/1/\"");
```

This happened to my website, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend an upgrade to the latest Joomla version.
It seems like you were hacked and your files are compromised. As clever as the hackers are, you are not gonna find "dodonet.biz" in your files.

I would search for weird `base64_decode` and `eval` snippets.
Or you can just compare your site with a clean joomla installation (or just the files) with [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) or a similar software.

You can find more informations about Joomla scurity on [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced)

Answer (score 0):

That page is not doing any redirect.

Try clearing your cache and reloading the web page.